# Creating user with same permissions in SQL Server and GRANT create user permission

Tags: sql, sql-server, permissions, sql-grant

Is it possible to add 'creating users' permission to SQL Server user? And then allow him only to create users with same permissions as this user?

Comment: I see that the last response was deleted by someone.I don't know why, it was very helpful. Is it possible to allow user to create other users by creating him with GRANT OPTION?